# Inline CKEditor not working in some HTML tags

Tags: html, ckeditor, grapesjs

CKEditor Inline standard-all version works only with few HTML tags line `<div>`, `<p>`, `<h1>`-`<h6>`. This inline editor not popping up for elements like `strong`, `i`, `span`,  etc.

I am using this inline editor inside grapesJS editor.

Here is [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Sinto990/b9m8n5ed/) where you can check the working & code.

**Version:**

grapesjs - 0.16.18

ckeditor - [standard-all - 4.14.1](https://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.14.1/standard-all/ckeditor.js)

Can we able to fix this issue by using `format_tags: "span;strong"`. Is there any other ways to fix this issue. Please let me know if any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got its solution as below:

```
CKEDITOR.dtd.$editable.span = 1
CKEDITOR.dtd.$editable.a = 1
CKEDITOR.dtd.$editable.strong = 1
CKEDITOR.dtd.$editable.em = 1
CKEDITOR.dtd.$editable.s = 1
CKEDITOR.dtd.$editable.u = 1
CKEDITOR.dtd.$editable.i = 1
CKEDITOR.dtd.$editable.p = 1
CKEDITOR.dtd.$editable.sub = 1
CKEDITOR.dtd.$editable.sup = 1
CKEDITOR.dtd.$editable.h1 = 1
CKEDITOR.dtd.$editable.h2 = 1
CKEDITOR.dtd.$editable.h3 = 1
CKEDITOR.dtd.$editable.h4 = 1
CKEDITOR.dtd.$editable.h5 = 1

CKEDITOR.disableAutoInline = true;
```

This not a core file update or something related to that. You can add this code in the place where you are customizing/doing your feature.

Here is [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Sinto990/xe48r7hy/) where you can check the working & code.

[Inline CKeditor integrated in GrapesJS editor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63700044/4229270)